# Using the data retrieved from Axios call

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to use the data I retrieve from an axios call. I get the correct info back in the response but when I try to return response I get undefined in the calling function. Is there a different way to return the response.data to the calling function?

```
  static getRequest(url) {
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
 axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: url,
  responseType:'json',
  withCredentials: true
})
  .then(response => {
   console.log(response.data);

    return response.data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log('___________ERROR RESPONSE__________');
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log('_________ERROR REQUEST_______');
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an 
      Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log('_________ERROR CONFIG_________');
    console.log(error.config);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to return your `axios` call from your `getRequest` function.

In the code you have above you are only returning your axios promise. The following code will return the value of the `response` when `getRequest` is invoked.

```
static getRequest(url) {

    return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
      responseType:'json',
      withCredentials: true
    }).then(response => {
       return response.data
    })

    //rest of code here
}
```